# Sending automatic push notification for inactivity Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app i'm using RPush Gem to implement push notifications. Right now admin can send a custom message as notification.

What I want is to send an automatic notification if the user hasn't logged in for 2 days. I can check this in my database where I'm keeping a record like last_logged. But i want to know how to check this automatically and run in background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to give better suggestions without more detail, but if you're on a platform like Heroku, you can do scheduled cron jobs using their scheduler add on.  So the idea is:

1)  Implement a rake task that checks whether a user hasn't logged in for 2 days, then send an email to yourself (or whomever)
2)  Schedule this rake task via [Heroku Scheduler add on](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler)

If you're not using Heroku, I'm sure there are equally compatible services you can try to run a cron job.

Comment: exactly dats what i want. can u re edit ur answer with one example for cron job.. i havent done that

Comment: @NidhinSG maybe [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) will help you.